# Generate multiple permutations in R

Tags: r, random, permutation

I have a data frame for which I want to shuffle the values in one column only, 1000 times while keeping the values in the rest of columns intact for random permutation test for a random forest classification. While I know how to generate 1 permutation using the `sample` in the base package, how do I obtain 1000 at once? Below is a screenshot of how the data looks like (it has approx 50k rows and 28 variables).
[image]

Some sample data can be generated using following:

```
data=data.frame(rep(1:3, each=10), rep(2:4, each=10), rep(10:12, each=10))
names(data)<-c("aH", "bH", "cH")
```

Comment: I question the premise of what you are trying to do here.  Random forests already have a permutation based importance metric which does something along the lines of what you have in mind, to determine how statistically meaningful the model is.

Comment: I agree, but it permutes within the rows. I am trying to shuffle the data in just one columns while keeping the order of data in other columns intact.

Comment: No, it takes the model and determines the validity of each predictor by randomly permuting values then seeing how to model changes.  I have never heard of someone doing what you are attempting.

Comment: Let me read more about it then :/

Comment: Just to be clear here, you _don't_ cross validate a random forest, because that basically already is happening as the forest gets built.  Once it has been built, there are number of importance metrics you can use to figure out how accurate the model is.

Comment: Looks like people are doing it - http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2017/10/12/1710248114.DCSupplemental/pnas.1710248114.sd02.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot comment on the validity of your analysis, I'll provide you a solution.

We loop over the vector 1:100 using `lapply` to generate 100 reproducible permutations of one column, bind it together with the rest of the data and store all samples in a list.

```
data=data.frame(rep(1:3, each=10), rep(2:4, each=10), rep(10:12, each=10))
names(data)<-c("aH", "bH", "cH")

test <- lapply(1:100, function(x){
  set.seed(x)
  cbind.data.frame(data[,1:2], sample(data[,3]))
})
```

Another option would be the `combinat` package and its function `permn()`, which generates all possible permutations of an input vector.

Comment: You don't need `nrow(data)` for `sample`. If it isn't supplied, the value is inferred from the first argument. See `?sample`. Good answer though.

Comment: @JosephWood Ah, you are right. I'll edit the answer accordingly.